# Kfold Cross Validation Uneven Split for Y

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, k-fold

I would like to split my data with sklearn.kfold. Here's my code

```
kf = KFold(n_splits = 10)

print(np.shape(X_1))
print(np.shape(y))


for train_index, test_index in kf.split(y):
        
    X_train, X_test = X_1.values[train_index], X_1.values[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    

print(np.shape(X_train))
print(np.shape(X_test))

print(np.shape(y_train))
print(np.shape(y_test))
```

Before split, the shapes of X and Y are (41437, 8) and (41437, ) respectively

After split X_train, X_test have (37294, 8), (4143, 8)
But Y has (29005,), (4143,)

A lot of Y data disappears from Y_train.

Where does it go?

Comment: uhmm very confusing. Why are you printing the shape of y_train? You probably mean Y_train.

Comment: @GaussianPrior Yeah, you are right. I made a mistake in the description. It is like you said in my code but still gives me a strange answer.

Comment: If the same error pops up then I don't know... Only thing I can tell you but I'm fairly confident it will not make any difference is to do for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_1) just to be precise and in accordance with https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html